# white space on the right side when browsing from mobile device

Tags: html, css

Whenever I open my [website](http://silexpro.com) through a mobile device I notice a white area to its right (which can be seen by scrolling horizontally). I've been trying to figure out what's causing it for hours to no avail.

i tried in css setting my body tag like the following, but the white space is always there,

```
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```

How can I remove this white area?

thank you

Comment: I've been in a similar situation. For me, it turned out to be an element that was overflowing its container. I found it by deconstructing my HTML - first try a page with just the header, then the header and the body, and then the header, body and footer. Keep an eye out for elements that have width with padding or margin set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Your header has rule for min-width.

```
#header{min-width:688px}
```

Try removing it, or making it `0`;

Comment: @bodgan this fixed it, thank you so much you are the master, i have another question if you know whats causing it, the fluid menu header is showing the black background when i first load the page on firefox and stays until i move the mouse (this only happens in firefox) do you know what might be causing this ?

Comment: @LucyKee you have `.scrolled` class on `body` when page loads. Which is causing this behavior.